# PHP get curl array results from inside a key value

Tags: php, oauth

I'm trying to get the access_token value from a curl response. The key value which is `[0]` renders out like so, `{"access_token":"430f8a7d4f721a9e51e3558689ff28ec592923d2","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer","scope":null}`.

However, I just need the value nested inside of `access_token`, which is `430f8a7d4f721a9e51e3558689ff28ec592923d2`.

The output is rendered using this:

```
$cmd="curl -u testuser:123456 http://localhost/oauth2/server/token.php -d 'grant_type=client_credentials'";
exec($cmd,$result);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($result[0]); echo '</pre>';
```

How might go about doing this?

Btw, none of this is sensitive data. I'm just experimenting with oauth2.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **json_decode** function on the results.

```
<?php
$json = '{"access_token":"430f8a7d4f721a9e51e3558689ff28ec592923d2","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer","scope":null}';

// Decode the JSON into an object
$decodedJson = json_decode($json);
$accessToken = $decodedJson->access_token;
var_dump($decodedJson,$accessToken);

// Decode the JSON into an array (note the true on the decode)
$decodedJson = json_decode($json,true);
$accessToken = $decodedJson['access_token'];
var_dump($decodedJson,$accessToken);
```

Comment: That's great. I didn't think of decoding the json. Though, I did try your snippet and it just dumped the son result and didn't encode the result. I wrangled this and it seems to get the token nicely: `$json = $result[0];
        $json = json_decode($json, true);
        echo $json['access_token'];`

Answer (score 0):

Encoding the json result, finds the subset.

```
$json = $result[0];
$json = json_decode($json, true);
echo $json['access_token'];
```